# Удаление устаревших данных из базы данных(Derby)

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, servlet, filter

Есть Web проект построенный на сервлетах и jsp. В базе данных хранится таблица, одно из полей хранит время для удаления.

Была мысль использовать фильтр который при каждом вызове сервлета будет проверять базу данных и удалять устаревшие данные. Может у derby есть какие то встроенные возможности для удаления записи по истечению срока? Не могу сообразить как это сделать лучше.

Запрос для удаления строки

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_table.delete_day==current_day
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать какой нибудь sheduler, запускаемый раз в день, или через заданный промежуток?

Comment: sheduler это java технология? или это к derby относится?

Comment: Это java технология,  вот [пример](http://devcolibri.com/1674) как создать на чистой java. Также можете использовать Quartz, Spring, в зависимости от технологий что у вас. К derby это никак не относится.

Comment: Это как сами придумаете. Можете в крон задать `java org.apache.derby.tools.ij my_file.sql`. Для j8 уже есть https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html . В Spring есть свой. И есть еще несколько реализаций, например Quartz.